# Use CSS in Conditional Statements

Tags: php, html, css

I'm fairly new to coding with **CSS and PHP**

To be more specific, is it possible to use "**display:**" for a **if-else statement?**

I'm trying to use pre-made variables and then get the sum of variables currently visible to the screen, which has

> "**display: block;**"

and ignore the value of variables that has

> "**display: none;**".

Thanks, in advance

I don't really have code for this but I'm trying to

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var c = 3;
```

let's say a and b are visible by

```
display: block;
```

then a function where it will scan all variables and then add all that is currently visible(which is **var a and b**)

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53275217/edit) the question and add your code as well, and explain the current vs. expected behavior.

Comment: Start loocking into javascript selectors. That should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I have quite understand what you want to do but here is the solution on what I have understood.

If you want to show hide on if and else then with jQuery you can use like this

```
if(true){
  $('.myClass').show();
}else{
  $('.myClass').hide();
}
```

If you want to use with PHP and CSS then add a class in div and write a css 
e.g :

CSS

```
.myClass.show{
  display:block;
}
.myClass.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
$val = 'show';

  if(false){
    $val = 'hide';
  } 
?>

<div class="myClass <?php echo $val ?>">Text </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm fairly new and only starting on jQuery. 
This helped me!